# preprocess_node is entered only for the first time

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I have a page where I want to show some results from the database, so I execute the query in hook_preprocess_node and pass a variable to the twig template.
the query works fine but only for the first time but after that the page get cached So I can not see the real data stored in the db.
When I clear the cache all works fine because the hook_preprocess_node is executed again.
I don't want to clear the cache each time.
What do you think the problem is, even I have disabled the twig cache ??

Answer (score 3):

If your query result depends from the url, you should set a context in the render array

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url';
```

or more specific context

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';
```

Docs. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Comment: i adding $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0; work this